# R: spatial interpolation with akima package on irregular grid with void data

Tags: r, interpolation, geospatial, missing-data, no-data

I have an irregular grid of points in the form (X,Y,Z), where (X,Y) are coordinates on a plane (can be geographical longitude/latitude), Z is some property to interpolate between points. I use `akima` interpolation package in R. The data set can contain missed values, and akima package does not like it. This can be remedied by a `complete.cases()` directive reorganizing the data set. But there is a following issue. Certain points contain no data in the sense that the interpolated quality is absent there (NA in R). As a closest example, Z is a depth of a stratigraphic interval, for example, Quaternary deposits. In these places I need to have a "hole" in the interpolated grid, showing that this layer is absent here; meanwhile the algorithm simply interpolates between available points with data.

```
#small extract from data
mydf<-read.csv(text="lon, lat, Q
411,362,1300
377,395.5,1425
427,370,1800
435.5,352,
428,357,
390,423,1700")


library("akima")
bbb<-data.frame(lon=mydf$lon,lat=mydf$lat,H=mydf$Q)
ccc<-bbb[complete.cases(bbb),]
Q.int<-interp(ccc$lon,ccc$lat,ccc$H,linear=TRUE,
extrap=FALSE,nx=240,ny=240,duplicate="mean")
```

Then it can be visualized, for example, with `image.plot()` from `fields` package

```
library("fields")
image.plot(Q.int)
```

In this data set, points 4,5 are lacking. This can be either 1) lack of data on these points, or 2) indication, that the deposits are absent here. I can note it in data set explicitly, for example, with NA symbol. But I need the interpolation, which distinguishes these two cases. 
My solution was to interpolate "as is", and then to use a trick: declare that all interpolated values of a property Z on a grid <30 meters are effectively NA's, and then plot it:

```
Q.int$z.cut<-ifelse(Q.int$z<30,NA,Q.int$z)
```

This could reflect the geological situation, since layers with decreasing thickness indeed "fade out", and can be stripped on a map, but would it be possible to arrange this problem in a more elegant solution?

[image: interpolated surface with NA values]